# sql unique records puzzle

Tags: sql, sql-server

The puzzle is to select unique pairs. Syntax in the following example is for Mssql

```
declare @t table (a int, b int)

insert into @t (a,b) values (1,2)
insert into @t (a,b) values (2,1)
insert into @t (a,b) values (1,3)
insert into @t (a,b) values (3,1)
insert into @t (a,b) values (5,6)


select * from @t -- it outputs 5 records.
```

I need to get unique pairs only regardless of the order a,b, which should give me three records

Output should be

```
(1,2),(1,3),(5,6)
```

I am out of ideas and will appreciate the help:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select      distinct 

            case when a<b then a else b end
           ,case when a<b then b else a end 

from        @t
;
```

Answer (score 10):

one way ([demo](http://rextester.com/UZZ77060)) would be

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.a,
                v.b
FROM   @t
       CROSS APPLY (VALUES(a,b),
                          (b,a)) v(a, b)
WHERE  v.a <= v.b
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't request for it, but this will preserve the order of columns, i.e. always return an existing row:

```
select a,b
from @t as t1
where not exists(
  select * from @t as t2
  where  t1.a = t2.b
    and t1.b = t2.a
    and t1.a > t2.a
);
```

Comment: Order is never guaranteed unless you have an `order by` clause.

Comment: @ShannonSeverance: here `order` means the order of columns, i.e. when there's only `(5,1)` the other solutions will return `(1,5)`, which doesn't exist. Edited my answer.